# Change a 1D NumPy array from (implicit) row major to column major order

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 1D array in NumPy that implicitly represents some 2D data in row-major order. Here's a trivial example:

```
import numpy as np
# My data looks like [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]]
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
```

I want to get a 1D array in column-major order (ie. `b = [1,5,2,6,3,7,4,8]` in the example above).
Normally, I would just do the following:

```
mat = np.reshape(a, (-1,4))
b = mat.flatten('F')
```

Unfortunately, the length of my input array is not an exact multiple of the row length I want (ie. `a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`), so I can't call `reshape`. I want to keep that extra data, though, which might be quite a lot since my rows are pretty long. Is there any straightforward way to do this in NumPy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some value to represent null to make the array be a multiple of how you want to split it. If casting to float is acceptable, you could use nan's to represent the added elements that represent nulls. Then reshape to 2D, call transpose, and reshape to 1D. Then eliminate the nulls.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]) # input
b = np.concatenate( (a, [np.NaN]) ) # add a NaN to make it 8 = 4x2
c = b.reshape(2,4).transpose().reshape(8,)  # reshape to 2x4, transpose, reshape to 8x1
d = c[-np.isnan(c)]  # remove NaN
print d

[ 1.  5.  2.  6.  3.  7.  4.]
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I can think of is *not* to try and use `reshape` with methods such as `ravel('F')`, but just to concatenate sliced views of your array.

For example:

```
>>> cols = 4
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
>>> np.concatenate([a[i::cols] for i in range(cols)])
array([1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4])
```

This works for any length of array and any number of columns:

```
>>> cols = 5
>>> b = np.arange(17)
>>> np.concatenate([b[i::cols] for i in range(cols)])
array([ 0,  5, 10, 15,  1,  6, 11, 16,  2,  7, 12,  3,  8, 13,  4,  9, 14])
```

---

Alternatively, use `as_strided` to reshape. The fact that the array `a` is too small to fit the `(2, 4)` shape doesn't matter: you'll just get junk (i.e. whatever's in memory) in the last place:

```
>>> np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=(2, 4))
array([[        1,         2,         3,         4],
       [        5,         6,         7, 168430121]])

>>> _.flatten('F')[:7]
array([1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4])
```

In the general case, given an array `b` and a desired number of columns `cols` you can do this:

```
>>> x = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(b, shape=(len(b)//cols + 1, cols)) # reshape to min 2d array needed to hold array b
>>> np.concatenate((x[:,:len(b)%cols].ravel('F'), x[:-1, len(b)%cols:].ravel('F')))
```

This unravels the "good" part of the array (those columns not containing junk values) and the bad part (except for the junk values which lie in the bottom row) and concatenates the two unraveled arrays. For example:

```
>>> cols = 5
>>> b = np.arange(17)
>>> x = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(b, shape=(len(b)//cols + 1, cols))
>>> np.concatenate((x[:,:len(b)%cols].ravel('F'), x[:-1, len(b)%cols:].ravel('F')))
array([ 0,  5, 10, 15,  1,  6, 11, 16,  2,  7, 12,  3,  8, 13,  4,  9, 14])
```

Comment: This works in the case where we only need to pad one number, but unfortunately I need to pad many. In a simple case, I might have [1,2,3,4,5,6], so calling `as_strided` gives [[1,2,3,4],[5,6, 9325823, 1204738]], which becomes [1,5,2,6,3,9325823,4,1204738] - now taking the first 6 elements doesn't remove the garbage :(

Comment: @GregOwen Apologies - I should have explained how the method can be extended to the general case in my answer. I've added it in now if you're interested (once you have an array and the number of columns, only two lines of code are needed to get the result!) :-)